# New Ember App with Ember 1.12.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

i want to build a new Ember CLI App with the Command: `Ember new demo-app`.

The Problem is, that i need Ember 1.12.2 and not the newest one.

How can i create an App with Ember 1.12.2?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It probably depends on your ember-cli version and package.json / bower.json dependencies.I have checked ember-cli args you can pass to 'ember new' but I do not see anything that lead to generating an app of specific version. Generally, it is recommended to have same version of ember-cli and ember (and ember-data).

Answer (score 4):

1. Install ember-cli `0.2.7` globally
2. `ember new demo-app`
3. Edit your bower.json so that `ember` is `1.12.2` and `ember-data` is `1.0.0-beta.19.2`
4. `bower install`
5. Edit your `package.json` so that `ember-data` matches version in `bower.json`
6. `npm install`
7. `ember s`
8. (Optional, but it will improve performance): Upgrade your project's `ember-cli` version as much as you would like to attempt. (expert step, unfortunately) (Technically it is possible to get all the way to ember-cli 2.5)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the 1.13 version from Ember CLI and downgrade Ember version to 1.12.2 in bower. It works smoothly.